# How to test my android app in all sdk versin of android?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-1.6

I developed one application in sdk 2.1. Now i want to test this in all sdk version. I trying to test in 2.2 ,1.6,1.5. But all get failed ,all throw exception. what are the changes I need be do in application to work in all sdk?

Please anyone help me to solve this issues.

Thanks

Comment: 2.2 Should run just fine, 1.6 and 1.5 are more limited and hence dont support everything 2.1 does. Compile over 1.5 instead of 2.1 so you can get a detailed report.

Comment: It could be helpful if you post the exceptions and the manifest content's

Answer (score 0):

Is your manifest set up to run in all versions of the code you are testing? Try looking at the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) on the subject.

Comment: i specified minsdk version as 3 and tarket version as 7 i didnt specified the maxsdk version .. Is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just set  minsdkVersion  in manifest file to 3. than your app will run on 1.5 and 1.6 also.